# PDF saved under Quote PDFs is not visible

Tags: pdf, quote

As we have limitations for custom Quote templates so we are trying to create VF page as PDF. Generated PDF is getting attached under object 'Quote PDFs' (API is QuoteDocument).
We're facing a problem that we're not able to view 
content in the PDF generated having size more than 32 KB. However the content is visible when we are sending the PDF via email.

Is there any way to view PDF in salesforce itself?

Please assist.

Comment: so you are saving the rendered PDF as a field in QuoteDocument? or are you saving it as an `Attachment` under `QuoteDocument` ?